# getting TypeError : XYZ is not a function in Angular

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, typeerror

I went through few questions and trying to solve this issue, but not getting success yet. I am getting this error :

> TypeError: appService.load_All_EV is not a function.

I used same way to call data from service in other controller and its working fine. 
This is my **service**.

```
app.factory("appService", function($http) {
    return {
        GetApp: function() {
            return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        },
        load_All_EV: function() {
            return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
        }
})
```

And my **controller** :-

```
app.controller('getActEvCtrl', ['$scope','$http','appService','$localStorage','$timeout','growl', function ($scope,$http,appService,$localStorage,growl,$timeout) {

            $scope.loadev = appService.load_All_EV();
            $scope.loadev.then(function(data) {

            angular.forEach(data, function(value) {
            $scope.getallEv = data;
            console.log(value);
            });
            });
}]);
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you handle the $http promise in the appService (you use "then"), and you do not pass a promise back to the controler, so you're probably get the error on line: "$scope.loadev.then".
remove the "then" from the service (also good practice) if you do not handle the promise there.

In the appService it should appear like this:

```js
load_All_EV: function() {
            return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help . Working . But can you explain when I used promise in service for other controllers using  earlier method , how was I not getting any errors ?

Comment: Strange, are you sure you handled it with "then"?

Comment: Yes , and response which I am getting is 5 times `{data: Array(9), status: 200, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "OK"}`. Due to this my ng repeat in view is also affecting.

Comment: Ok , I edited the code. Getting single object now , But I am unable to fetch data from inside the object.

Comment: Please consider to iterate on your data like that:

  $scope.loadev.then(function(data) {
           var dataArr = data.data;
            dataArr.forEach(function(value) {
            console.log(value);
            });
});

Work on the data array directly, no need to use angular.forEach method.

Comment: You are right . I did `$scope.getallEnv = data.data;` and now I am able to fetch . Thank you again

Comment: Cheers! glad to help.